# How to get location coordinates of YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, coordinates

How to get location coordinates of a YouTube video, if already specified by the user in the advanced settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Client API](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client)

This is a Java API.

You will find a class `GeolocationSearch` which has the following method

```
String getInputLocation()
```

This can get you the coordinates.

Comment: Can you give an example for how to get video coordinates using a youtube video id? Many thanks.

Comment: how are these even answers?